# Iterate the files in an ADLS2 Azure Datalake Directory given a SAS url

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'd like to download the files from a ADLS2 Storage blob directory - I have only a SAS url to the said directory, and I would like to recursively download all the files in that directory.

It is very clear how to do this given the storage credentials, and there are many examples that show how to do it - but I couldn't find any which uses a SAS url.

Any clues or documentation links would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you would use with account credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment, and I got expected results as below and I have taken code from @ROGER ZANDER's [Blog](https://rzander.azurewebsites.net/download-files-from-azure-blob-storage-with-powershell/):

```
function DownloadBlob {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$URL,
        [string]$Path = (Get-Location)
    )
    
    $uri = $URL.split('?')[0]
    $sas = $URL.split('?')[1]
    $newurl = $uri + "?restype=container&comp=list&" + $sas 
    $body = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $newurl 
    $xml = [xml]$body.Substring($body.IndexOf('<')) 
    $files = $xml.ChildNodes.Blobs.Blob.Name
    $files | ForEach-Object { $_; New-Item (Join-Path $Path (Split-Path $_)) -ItemType Directory -ea SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
        (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($uri + "/" + $_ + "?" + $sas, (Join-Path $Path $_))
     }
}
```

Then call DownloadBlob Function and Give SAS URL.

**Output:**

[image]

In Local Machine Downloaded File:

[image]